# How is the name of the letter "Z" pronounced in Indian English?

Tags: pronunciation, subcontinental-english, alphabet

How is the letter "Z" pronounced in Indian English?

I assumed that Indian English is more similar to British English than to American English, and therefore would pronounce it "Zed". But I came across the Wikipedia article about the Indian company [Zee Entertainment Enterprises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zee_Entertainment_Enterprises), which has a logo of the letter "Z" but has "ZEE" written underneath.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Z#English) doesn't indicate how the letter is pronounced in Indian English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. We call it 'Zed', even though ZEE TV has been around for ages. We don't associate the company's name with the letter's pronunciation. Some of us aren't even aware that Americans call the letter 'Zee'.

However, 'Zee' is slowly becoming popular due to the influence of American English here. For example, people with names starting with 'Z' can be nicknamed 'Zee'. People in the software industry, (who communicate with America a lot,) may call a variable 'Zee' as against 'Zed'.